# Two meanings of modulo?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In the following statement, it seems "mod" serves two separate functions.

$(ab)\textrm{ mod } n \equiv \big((a\textrm{ mod } n)\cdot(b\textrm{ mod } n)\big)\textrm{ mod } n$

- There is the use as a qualification of a statement about equivalence, as in the final "mod n": "these two expressions (LHS and RHS of $\equiv$) are equivalent mod n."
- There is the use as an operator applied to a single expression, as in all the other occurences.

Is there any ambiguity here? Any potential mathematical hazards that can arise from not being clear about the distinction?

EDIT - thinking on, I can see that the final "mod n" could be interpreted in either sense...)

Comment: There's a difference between the way mathematicians and programmers use "mod".  The former refers to an equivalence class, the latter to a remainder (the least positive member of the equivalence class).  Both usages are fine, but the difference between them can cause some confusion.

Comment: So what about the mixture in the statement in the question - is it correct by the standards of either camp?

Comment: The statement I would prefer is that if $a\equiv A \pmod n$ and $b\equiv B\pmod n$ then $ab\equiv AB \pmod n$.  good enough?

Comment: Nevertheless, your statement is also correct. (Follows by Lulu's comment.)

Comment: Wow, that was impressive for you to accurately locate and articulate that difference!

Comment: Depending on your interpretation, some of the followings may be wrong:

$$\begin{align*}
7 &\equiv 1 \pmod 3\\
7 &\equiv 1 \mod 3\\
7 &\equiv 1 \bmod 3\\
7 &= 1 \bmod 3\\
7 &= 7 \bmod 3\\
1 &= 7 \bmod 3\\
7 \bmod 3 &= 1\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Depending on the context, perhaps the author has some other meaning in mind for "$\equiv$". For example, it might signify that this formula is an identity true for all integers $a$ and all integers $b$ rather than something that expresses a relationship between particular values of $a$ and $b.$ To know what was meant I think you have to read a good part of the earlier text to see how these symbols are used there. If you have no access to text associated with this formula then you can only guess.

Comment: @lulu mod is also widely used by mathematicians. The difference has nothing to do with profession.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. Rather there is an error. Either the congruence sign should be an equality,  or else you need a final $\pmod n$ if you intend it to be a congruence. See the "Beware" in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3):

It is customary to write the equivalence relation as $a \equiv b \pmod m$, **with parenthesis around** $\bmod m$ and a bigger space between $a \equiv b$ and $\bmod m$.

Even $\TeX$ (and $\LaTeX$ and MathJax) do that with the appropiate commands:

The equivalence relation `a \equiv b \pmod n` renders as $a \equiv b \pmod n$

The binary operation `a = b \bmod n` renders as $a = b \bmod n$

That usually suffices to avoid ambiguity since it wouldn't make sense to put parenthesis like that in the $\bmod$ operation.

The expression you have probably should be written like

$$(a b) \bmod n \equiv ((a \bmod n)\cdot(b \bmod n)) \pmod n$$

if the intention is that the three first $\bmod$'s denote the operation and the last one denotes the equivalence relation or

$$(a b) \bmod n = ((a \bmod n)\cdot(b \bmod n)) \bmod n$$

if the intention is that the four $\bmod$'s denote the operation (notice that in this case, one should use $=$ instead of $\equiv$).